# writefln() throws: Incorrect format specifier: %(%s, %)

Tags: d, dmd

Why does it throw exception:

```
import std.stdio;

void main(string[] args) {
    try{
        writefln("My items are %(%s, %).", [1,2,3]);
    }catch(Exception x){
        writefln("oops: %s", x.msg);
    }
}
```

([you can build and test the code at Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/ntYfGx))

The result I get is:

```
My items are oops: /usr/lib/dmd2/src/phobos/std/format.d(1592): 
Incorrect format specifier: %(%s, %).
```

According to http://dlang.org/phobos/std_format.html it should work...

Comment: Works For Me™ with dmd 2.065

Comment: @SergeiNosov, but you can see at [Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/ntYfGx) that it doesn't work. Their version is 2.042, but I seriously doubt that's the reason..

Comment: That is *exactly* the reason. `%(...%)` was added in DMD 2.058 (or around that version). 2.042 was released in March 2010 - that version is four years old!

Comment: Works fine on DPaste: http://dpaste.dzfl.pl/e24ec79ae6a6

Answer (score 7):

Please use a more recent D compiler. You can download the latest version of the reference D compiler from http://dlang.org/download.html, or you can compile and run a D program online on http://dpaste.dzfl.pl/.

Answer (score 4):

It works perfectly fine with a recent compiler. If you're using ideone.com to test this, then that's bound to be your problem. 2.042 is years old now, and it's highly likely that the functionality that you're trying to use was added since then. Looking at the documentation that came with the zip file for 2.042, the documentation for std.format has changed dramatically since then. So, I'd say that the problem is that you're using what is effectively an ancient compiler version. ideone.com hasn't updated their D compiler in years, making them a horrible site to test D code on, *especially* if it's functionality in the standard library that you're testing out rather than the language itself.

If you want to try compiling D code online, I'd suggest that you try out [dpaste](http://dpaste.dzfl.pl/home). It actually has an up-to-date D compiler, because it's designed specifically for compiling D code examples online.